# Error message during angular loading with custom directives and dynamical ng-class

Tags: angularjs, directive, ng-class

I'm receiving angular error: Cannot read property '3' of undefined.
I have ng-class function definition in controller

```
$scope.waterclass = function(valveid, orient)
{
    return $scope.tasks[valveid].scheduled ? "water-static water-flow" : "water-static" ;
}
```

($scope.tasks[valveid].scheduled - tasks is some array that is initialized in controller)
then I have directive

```
app.directive("myPipe", function() {
return {
    template : function(elem, attr) {
        return '<div ng-class="waterclass('+attr.valveid+')></div>'
           }

       };
});
```

and finally HTML element with directive

```
<my-pipe valveid="3"></my-pipe>
```

notice that valveid is 3 and that value is shown in error message.
The strange thing is that all works correctly but this error message at the page loading and no more errors during runtime.
BTW, I've found way out using

```
ng-class="{'class1':expression,...}"
```

construction in my directive, but I just wonder what I'm doing wrong or maybe there is some bug?

Comment: Could you edit your question and add your expression here: `some valveid expression` ?

Comment: $scope.tasks[valveid].scheduled - is the expression

Comment: So this means that `$scope.tasks` is not initialized at the moment your directive is initialized and its template is compiled and `waterclass` method is called.

Comment: does directive initialization evaluates template?
And does it initialized before controller initialization?

Comment: [angularjs expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) have **forgiving** feature: they will be evaluated to `undefined`/`null` without throwing errors. That is why `ng-class="{'class1':expression,...}"` will work without any error messages.